# Can't find QtBluetooth Header/Cant include it in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, qtbluetooth

its my first Question here :)

Im trying to develop a C++ Application which i can use to control a Lego NXT remotely from my Desktop PC over Bluetooth. To achieve this i want to use the QBluetooth Library(and other QtGui Libs aswell).

My Problem is the QBluetooth Headers are not there. When i look into the /usr/include/qt5 directory i get this:

```
paul@Paul-RoboAG:/usr/include/qt5$ ls
QtConcurrent  QtNetwork           QtPrintSupport    QtQuickTest  QtXml
QtCore        QtOpenGL            QtQml             QtSql
QtDBus        QtOpenGLExtensions  QtQuick           QtTest
QtGui         QtPlatformSupport   QtQuickParticles  QtWidgets
paul@Paul-RoboAG:/usr/include/qt5$ find | grep Blue
paul@Paul-RoboAG:/usr/include/qt5$ find | grep blue
paul@Paul-RoboAG:/usr/include/qt5$
```

I dont find the headers, and when i want to include them in my App(in QtCreator) the AutoCompletion wont find it. I Already added "bluetooth" to "QT" in my project file.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-05-16T21:06:59
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += bluetooth

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = NXT-Control
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        nxtcontroller.cpp

HEADERS  += nxtcontroller.h
```

Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: Which qt version are you trying to use? How did you install QtBluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

1) wget http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.0-rc/submodules/qtconnectivity-opensource-src-5.3.0-RC.tar.xz

2) tar xvpf qtconnectivity-opensource-src-5.3.0-RC.tar.xz

3) cd qtconnectivity-opensource-src-5.3.0-RC

4) qmake -r

5) make

6) sudo make install

Then, I see this:

```
ls /usr/include/qt/QtBluetooth/
5.3.0/                             qbluetoothglobal.h                 qbluetoothserver.h                 QBluetoothTransferManager          qbluetoothuuid.h
QBluetoothAddress                  qbluetooth.h                       QBluetoothServiceDiscoveryAgent    qbluetoothtransfermanager.h        QtBluetooth
qbluetoothaddress.h                QBluetoothHostInfo                 qbluetoothservicediscoveryagent.h  QBluetoothTransferReply            QtBluetoothDepends
QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent     qbluetoothhostinfo.h               QBluetoothServiceInfo              qbluetoothtransferreply.h          QtBluetoothVersion
qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent.h   QBluetoothLocalDevice              qbluetoothserviceinfo.h            QBluetoothTransferRequest          qtbluetoothversion.h
QBluetoothDeviceInfo               qbluetoothlocaldevice.h            QBluetoothSocket                   qbluetoothtransferrequest.h        
qbluetoothdeviceinfo.h             QBluetoothServer                   qbluetoothsocket.h                 QBluetoothUuid
```

As for `find | grep blue` -> you may wish to take a look at the `-(i)name` option.

`QT += core gui` is needless because the core and gui modules are added by default. I know that QtCreator adds it by default, but it is wrong. It is good to be aware of it.

Comment: It works, QT Creator provides AutoCompletion for it aswell, but is there package in the official repos?

Comment: @CaptainRuhrpott: I gave the official repository of the Qt Project. You mean the official repository of your distribution? Then the answer is no.

Comment: I mean is there something i can install over apt? I installed the standard qt packages with qt5-default, is there a way to do the same with such addons